# Help me identify a novel I read back in the late 70’s or early 80’s -- "Eureka" and hi-tech astral projection

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm trying to identify a novel I read back in the late 70’s or early 80’s.  As I recall it, the story synopsis would be that a man and woman team are researching a machine they’re designing to induce a temporary telepathic or out-of-body/ESP type experience.  As the story progresses, a wrecked alien space ship is discovered with a body in it.  Eventually the lead characters encounter an out-of-body alien entity that ends up being evil or a criminal and has been interfering with their efforts.  The lead scientist ends up using his machine to completely rip his consciousness from his body so that he can fight the alien on the “astral plane” or whatever that he’s on.  I also recall this book introducing me to the word “eureka,” which was a central focal point at one point.  In all, this story had some really great concepts, although I can’t recall now how well the story might hold up today.  I’d still love to figure out what it was and take another look.  Thanks for any help anyone there can provide.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Mind from Outer Space](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4588) by Eando Binder

The very first word in the novel is "Eureka".

A couple of scientists from Serendipity Labs stumble over a crashed alien flying saucer. An alien criminal with no physical body lurks inside, and is trying to take over the Earth. The scientists at Serendipity have to develop astral projection, telepathy, and other new science to combat the menace.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That's it!  I also remember the Serendipity Labs as being another unusual word  used in this book (although I was thinking that it was Serendipidity Labs, as I recall seeing that used somewhere).  Amazingly, Amazon has it on Kindle, so I've already ordered it.  Thanks again!